# Report Designer Work Calendar Date Difference

Tags: acumatica

I have a report that shows the days late for an order using the DateDiff function comparing today to a custom field we have called ShipBy.  It works well enough in that I get the total days overdue, including weekends and holidays, but the customer needs to see it by Work Days overdue.  In other words, exclude weekends and holidays so that it only shows the actual work days that an order is overdue.

Does the Report Designer have anything built in that can calculate a DateDiff using the Acumatica Work Calendar?  Is there another way to go about this in the report designer other than creating a custom function and a DAC populated with the available Work Dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no formula function that I know of that allows that. Report formulas operate on primitive types, Acumatica work calendar is a complex type. Having  scripting functions that works on Acumatica assemblies complex types would be redundant with the graph functions.

You can look up the Date/Time formula functions here:
https://help.acumatica.com/(W(25))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=00a69dbb-c06b-4ce4-8b29-e86ee0e8ed47

The query builder in the report designer is also not a good fit for complex business rule. I believe you should use the appropriate layer for business rules code which is the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in a GI.

```
=(DateDiff('d', [PeriodStart], [Now])) + 1 - DateDiff('w', DateAdd([PeriodStart], 'd' , 0 -(DayOfWeek([PeriodStart]) -1)) , DateAdd([Now], 'd', 2 - DayOfWeek( [PeriodStart]) )) * 2 - Switch((DateDiff('d', [PeriodStart], [Now]) + 1) % 7 > 0 And DayOfWeek([PeriodStart]) = 1, 1,(DateDiff('d', [PeriodStart], [Now]) + 1) % 7 + DayOfWeek( [PeriodStart]) = 8, 1,(DateDiff('d', [PeriodStart], [Now]) + 1) % 7 + DayOfWeek( [PeriodStart]) > 8, 2,True, 0)
```